# Why SQL Data Sync requires Alter Database permission on SQL Server on premise DB?

Tags: sql, azure, synchronization, tracking

We are using SQL data sync tool to syncronize on premise DB with cloud. But while provisioning, the data sync throws up the error message that it requires ALTER DATABASE.permission for the SQL id on SQL Server on-premise Database. We did lot of digging to find out the reason and it looks like it uses ALTER DATABASE command to change the `<change_tracking_option>`. Does this mean if `<change_tracking_option>` is enabled, it will not create the change tracking triggers for each tables?  But if it does create it , then why it requires ALTER DATABASE permission?

Answer (score 2):

SQL Azure Data Sync is based on the Sync Framework and I think this is happening because the Sync Framework is trying to enable snapshot isolation on your database.

Comment: Sql Azure Data Sync doesnt use the built-in SQL Change Tracking, so Voclare is right, the provisioning is setting the transaction isolation.